# how to invoke search box in android?

Tags: android

i've tried to create simple search app and followed the documentation in android site..
but no luck...

These are the requirements in creating the search dialog:

1. Search Config file in res/xml folder.
2. Searchable Activity declared in the manifest.
3. And another activity that uses Searchable activity to do the search stuff.

the search box can be invoke by calling

```
  @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onSearchRequested();
    }
```

also use...

```
    this.onSearchRequested();
    return true;
```

for the button

none of them working...
i used both hardware and software invoke but no search dialog appear...
please help....

Comment: I am having similar problem as well and docs are not very clear on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the meta data element for you search config file in your manifest? If not, try adding this:

```
<activity>
...
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

in your searchable activity where @xml/searchable points to your config file (searchable.xml in this example).

Comment: yes but not working. what i did is place the meta data below the activity tag (all classes) and it worked (i can new search), but the drawback is that if user accidentally hit the search hardware button the search box most likely to pop up. I don't know why it is not working in specific class

Answer (score 0):

Better include meta-data tag in application tag, instead of declaring that tag in each and every activity tags. Even if u don't want search functionality in some of the activities, no worries. Just override onSearchRequested() method and return false.